# PHP appears to be encountering segfault when using finfo_file method

Tags: php, gentoo, segmentation-fault

I have encountered a strange bug. When trying to determine mime type of file using Fileinfo (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) extension, PHP (or Apache? see below.) is appearing to be crashing.

Code:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, null);
$info = finfo_file($finfo, "index.php");
```

When opening from web (through apache2), segfault is reported in error log:

```
[Wed Oct 23 14:32:25 2013] [notice] child pid 29084 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

When executing from cli e.g. `php -q test.php`, output is okay.

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.4-pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Oct 18 2013 19:11:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

/usr/sbin/apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 20 2013 14:16:11
```

Any clues?

Comment: Posted a comment also on the php bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57386

Answer (score 0):

Don`t you try solution from https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=467756 it looks like there is a similar problem.

> Some further comments on how I managed to work around the problem by
> switching apache2 from mod_php to php-fpm usage:
>
> 1. edited /etc/portage/package.use and added use flag "fpm" to dev-lang/php
> 2. remerged php by "emerge php"
> 3. installed fastcgi module via "emerge mod_fastcgi_handler"
> 4. edited /etc/conf.d/apache2 added "-D FASTCGI_HANDLER" and removed "-D PHP5"
> 5. edited /etc/php/fpm-php5.4/php-fpm.conf and changed "listen" statement to use a socket via "listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock"
> 6. edited
>    /etc/apache2/modules.d/20_mod_fastcgi_handler.conf and added
>    AddHandler fcgi:/var/run/php-fpm.sock .php .php5 .phtml .phps
>    DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml
>    at the end of the
> 7. restarted apache and started php-fpm
>
> After switching to php-fpm using this procedure the apache crashes are
> instantly gone and my example scripts work as expected. Thus, I highly
> suspect mod_php being the cultrip.

or maybe you need to add USE=nss for apr-utils.

P.S. show use flags, not only version of problem programs.

P.P.S Dont you foget to add apache2 use flag to php (it is off by default)